# Does a UK citizen need a transit visa for Pakistan?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, uk-citizens, pakistan

I know, dumb question again but I am struggling to get "consistent" information and wondering if anyone here had a similar experience. That and I'm having issues contacting airline/embassy, so thought I might just ask here in the meantime.

I bought cheap flights (feel free to berate me as much as I am myself for it) that do the following:

London --> Lahore (connecting flight) ---> Islamabad ---> Beijing --> Tokyo.

Ticket shows onward to Tokyo. I am in Pakistan for less than 24 hours (19 to be exact).

I am a British National (dual citizen of Australia by descent). I am assuming the connecting flight from Lahore to Islamabad is domestic. However, if I have an onward ticket showing that I am leaving the country, do I really need a transit visa for this? If I'm just stupid (which I'm confident I am), is someone able to break down why?

Cheers and let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're flying domestically within Pakistan, you will enter Pakistan, and as such will require a transit visa.

If flying the same route back, make sure to apply for a double-entry transit visa.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. Hopefully all goes well then. Feel a bit annoyed the airline nor my travel agency didn't tell me about this, but alas, my fault. I will have to confirm however if this is actually a domestic flight, its an ATV so thats where the word "assumption" comes in. Hope this helps someone in future :)

Comment: Lahore and Islamabad are both in Pakistan. This can only be a domestic flight...

Comment: @LV426 What dda said. There is one flight in India and one in Morocco having a domestic stopover but counting as international flights, but no such thing in Pakistan.